# Is grep syntax different from regex?

Tags: grep

I want to extract name of removed packages from here "cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'remove'"

```
 2013-09-09 15:57:34 remove activity-log-manager:i386 0.9.4-0ubuntu6.2 <none>
 2013-09-09 15:57:35 remove activity-log-manager-control-center:i386 0.9.4-0ubuntu6.2 <none>
 2013-09-09 15:57:38 remove alacarte:all 3.6.1-0ubuntu3 <none>
 2013-09-09 15:57:41 remove deepin-software-center:all 2.1.2.1~precise~NoobsLab.com <none>
```

I want to grab only name of the packages between remove and colon after package name. 
I am not a regex expert, I made a regex expression that seems to do the job but when I want to apply it with grep nothing happens.
Here is working regex pattern in regex evaluators

```
(?<=remove)(.*?)(?=:)
```

But this is not working :

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'remove' | grep '(?<=remove)(.*?)(?=:)'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not an expert either and so don't dare post an answer but the following code works for me: `grep -E '[0-9] remove' dpkg.log | sed -nrs 's/:/ /g;p' | awk '{ print $6 }'`. As for grep versus "regex", I understand you need to use `grep -E`, the usage of `egrep` being frowned upon, for full regex functionality.

Comment: BTW, the `[0-9] `is needed to eliminate lines like `2013-09-11 11:11:08 startup packages remove`

Comment: Thank you vasa1, your solution does what I want yet I need to know why my expression in grep doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a common core of regular expression syntax however there are distinct flavors. Your expression appears to contain some features specific to the perl flavor, in particular the use of complex *lookaround assertions* describing the start and end of the pattern to be matched, whereas grep defaults to a basic regular expression (BRE) syntax that only supports a simpler set of these *zero-length matches* such as line- (`^`,`$`) and word-anchors (`\>`, `\<`).

You can enable perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE) support in grep using the -P command line switch (although note that the man page currently describes it as "experimental"). In your case you probably want the -o switch as well to only print the matching pattern, rather than the whole line i.e.

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'remove' | grep -oP '(?<=remove)(.*?)(?=:)'
```

Be aware that this expression may fail if it encounters packages that do not have the :i386 suffix since it may read ahead to a matching colon in the next word, e.g.

```
echo "2013-09-07 08:31:44 remove cifs-utils 2:5.1-1ubuntu2 <none>" | grep -oP '(?<=remove)(.*?)(?=:)'
 cifs-utils 2
```

You may wish to look at awk instead e.g.

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | awk '$3 ~ /remove/ {sub(":.*", "", $4); print $4}'
```

As well as BRE and PCRE, Gnu grep has a further mode called *extended regular expression* (ERE), specified by the -E command line switch. The man page notes that

```
In  GNU grep,  there is  no difference in available functionality 
between basic and extended syntaxes.
```

However you should note that "no difference in available functionality" does **not** mean that the syntax is the same. For example, in BRE the `+` character is normally treated as literal, and only becomes a modifier meaning 'one or more instance of the preceding regular expression' if escaped, i.e.

```
$ echo "123.456" | grep '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
$ echo "123.456" | grep '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'
123.456
```

whereas for ERE it is exactly the opposite

```
$ echo "123.456" | grep -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
123.456
$ echo "123.456" | grep -E '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'
```

A similar distinction applies for `sed` invoked without and with the `-r` switch.

Comment: wow, that did the trick, I would go crazy since I didn't find any reference about it.
Thank you steeldriver! You saved my day.

Comment: I just read your updated post, you gave valuable info for beginners, thanks a lot steeldriver.

Answer (score 1):

From the `grep` man page:

> grep  searches  the  named  input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN.

As far as I know, `grep` has no ability to edit the lines that it matches; I would use `sed` or possibly `tr` for that. Any of the following should get what you want:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'remove' | sed 's/.*remove \([^:]*\):.*/\1/'
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'remove' | sed -E 's/.*remove ([^:]*):.*/\1/'
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | sed -n '/remove/s/.*remove \([^:]*:\).*/\1/p'
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | sed -nE '/remove/s/.*remove ([^:]*):.*/\1/p'
```

I'm honestly not sure what your `(?<=remove)(.*?)(?=:)` is trying to accomplish. In regex, brackets are used to define capture groups: you can see that I've used them in the sed commands here -- in there, everything matched will be replaced by the contents of the capture group `/1`, the first group to be defined.

Comment: I just put them together with trial and error method, I  don't know even if it's verbose, but it worked. Thank you for clarification about sed and awk, I heard that awk  could create miracles