# Why is my grep + regex not working?

Tags: grep

I recently decided that enough was enough -- I was going to learn to use grep fluently.  It's been all of three hours and I'm already stumped by this toy problem.

I'm currently syncing a RAID5 array, the progress of which can be monitored by reading `/proc/mdstat`.  The output of `cat /proc/mdstat` is shown below.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid5 sda4[0] sdb4[1] sdc4[2]
      5858765824 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      [=============>.......]  resync = 67.3% (1972073120/2929382912) finish=205.7min speed=77537K/sec

md0 : active raid5 sda3[0] sdb3[1] sdc3[2]
      998400 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

For fun, I thought I would use `watch` to monitor `/proc/mdstat` in real time, pipe it's output into grep, and show only the estimated remaining time.

My approach is as follows:

`watch cat /proc/mdstat | grep finish=\d+\.\d | grep \d+\.\d`

I'm stumped as to why this produced no output.  In fact, the first grep expression produces no output, even though it seems to work on [Regex101](http://regex101.com).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use `\d` and always quote a regex inside `grep`. See [‘grep’ regular expression syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to use Perl regex syntax you need `-P` switch with grep. Check out previously asked guestion here [Is grep syntax different from regex?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348666/is-grep-syntax-different-from-regex/348703#348703)

Answer (score 13):

- You should quote your expression so the shell doesn't interpret it
- `grep` doesn't have the `\d` escape, you'll need to use `[0-9]` instead.
- `+` needs to be escaped without the `-E` switch.

This should work:

```
watch cat /proc/mdstat | grep 'finish=[0-9]\+\.[0-9]' | grep '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]'
```

Comment: @blz The grep supports 3 'styles' of regular expressions: "basic" -G (default), "extended" -E and "perl" -P. The basic mode requires that `?, +, {, |, (, and )` be escaped to have special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` instead, this worked for me:

```
watch "cat /proc/mdstat | grep 'finish\=' | sed -e 's/.*finish\=\([0-9,\.]*\).*/\1/g'"
```

Comment: The OP wants *"to learn to use **grep** fluently."*